# Cannot do updates in OSX app store

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, macos

I am at a loss.

I have upgrade to Mavericks and now when i go to my App store i see there are 6 new updates. When i click on Updates (showing Updates 6) i only get a grey bar and it does not show any of updates. I have tried everything. Including reinstalling mavericks. My next choice would to do a total clean install. Is there any way to fix this? I do have screen shots but having trouble uploading them.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered that before, particularly at times when Apple's update servers are under heavy load, as they are now (due to the new OS X release and accompanying software updates). As far as I can tell, it's typically a problem with the indicator itself, rather than updates being missing. I wouldn't worry too much about it, chances are it will fix itself in a few days.